# Converting fuel consumption

Tags: python-3.x

A car's fuel consumption may be expressed in many different ways. For example, in Europe, it is shown as the amount of fuel consumed per 100 kilometers.

In the USA, it is shown as the number of miles traveled by a car using one gallon of fuel.

Your task is to write a pair of functions converting l/100km into mpg, and vice versa.

The functions:

are named l100kmtompg and mpgtol100km respectively;
take one argument (the value corresponding to their names)
Complete the code in the editor.

Run your code and check whether your output is the same as ours.

Here is some information to help you:

1 American mile = 1609.344 metres;
1 American gallon = 3.785411784 litres.

def l100kmtompg(liters):

def mpgtol100km(miles):

Comment: Take a look at [pint](https://pint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Answer (score 0):

I know the  question is confusion , cuz I spent hours doing this. ngl this is the real question

3.9 is the value given
so for first function
100*0.625/(3.9 *0.265)

2nd def(60.3)
(3.78/(60.3 * 1.6))*100